# How do I write a custom application launcher that runs an application as a specific group?

Tags: linux-mint, desktop, mate-desktop, application, .desktop

I am running Linux Mint Mate 18.2, from my console I currently run an application as a specific group using the following command

```
sudo -g my-group "/home/me/apps/my.app/bin/start.sh" %f
```

This launches the application however if I try to put this command in my custom application launcher to add to my panel it does not run. I tried substituting `sudo` for `gksudo` but still did not launch the application.

Is there something that I'm doing wrong or missing? Would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

If your user is already a member of the group you want to run the process in, you can use [**`sg`**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man1/sg.1.html) instead of `sudo` to change the primary group in which the process executes.

```
sg <newgroup> <command>
```

Additional advantage for `sg` over `sudo` is that you do not need additional privileges or configuration.

Comment: is there a way to do it without being a member of the group?